# A problem on correlation and independence

Tags: probability, correlation, independence

Here is a little challenge/problem for you guys.

Let $(X,Y)$ be jointly discrete RVs such that each have at most two mass points (not necessarily $1$ and $0$, i.e. not necessarily indicator variables). Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. Are they independent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're dealing with correlation, you can restrict consideration to 0-1 variables without loss of generality. Any linear rescaling of the 0-1 variables to $a$ and $b$ leaves the correlation unaltered. So if it's true of 0-1 variables, it's true of distributions with mass points at some arbitrary $a$ and $b$, with $a\neq b$.

Since the Pearson correlation for binary variables is the [phi coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient), and $n \phi^2$ is the chi-square, the immediate implication for binary variables is that zero correlation implies independence.

Comment: Great reasoning! :) This is elegant. :)

Comment: I started by doing the first line of the algebra; realized I already knew the answer and thought - "why not just explain why I know?"

Comment: That's good enough. I was actually looking for the answer that one can linearly rescale any set of dichotomous RVs into indicator variables without affecting the correlation, which you did! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer with no jargon about $\chi^2$ <s>random variables</s> statistics.

If $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli random variables with parameters $p$ and $q$
respectively, then 
$E[X] = p = P\{X=1\}$ and $E[Y] = q = P\{Y=1\}$. Also, 
$$E[XY] = 1\cdot 1\cdot P\{X=1,Y=1\} = P\{X=1,Y=1\}.$$
Now, if the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are 
uncorrelated, then $$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y] = 0
~\Rightarrow ~E[XY] = pq$$
which shows that $P\{X=1, Y = 1\} = P\{X=1\}P\{Y=1\}$, that is, the
*events* $\{X=1\}$ and $\{Y=1\}$ are *independent events.*  It follows 
from standard properties of two independent events that
the events $\{X=1\}$ and $\{Y=0\}$ also are independent events, as are
$\{X=0\}$ and $\{Y=1\}$, as well as $\{X=0\}$ and $\{Y=0\}$. In other
words, $$P\{X=i, Y=j\} = P\{X=i\}P\{Y=j\}~ \text{for all}~ i,j \in \{0,1\}$$
showing that $X$ and $Y$ are *independent random variables.*

Now, if $X$ and $Y$ are *any* independent random variables,
then so are $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ independent random variables (for
arbitrary measurable functions $g$ and $h$), so that
if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated Bernoulli random variables, and thus
independent random variables, $aX+b$ and $cY+d$ are also
independent random variables and hence uncorrelated random variables.
The latter can also be inferred using Glen_b's remark that
linear transformations don't affect the covariance and
the (Pearson) correlation coefficient, that is,
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(aX+b, cX+d) &= \operatorname{cov}(X,Y),\\
\rho_{aX+b,cY+d} &= \rho_{X,Y}\end{align}$$

Comment: The previous answer makes no reference to $\chi^2$ random variables (which aren't involved in this problem): it invokes the fact that a $\chi^2$ *statistic* (which is based on squared differences) can be zero only in a very special circumstance. The economy of its argument is noteworthy.

Comment: +1 It's good to put this argument as well; it's a (better) version of the line argument I began to write before I decided to post the one I did. (I had planned to come back and add such an argument in later; yours is no doubt better than what I'd have written)